# Finding all sum of 2 power value combination values of a given number in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

R data frame 1 :

| Index | Powervalue |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 32 |

R dataframe 2 :

| CombinedValue |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 50 |

Attached expected output image.

[image: Expected output]

One of stackoverflow mate provided below code. Am looking how to fix
Columns till power 31 as shown in attached image. The columns match with possiblecodes then place 1 and 0 else 0 for the remaining columns. Please help.

```
toCodes <- function(x) {
  n <- floor(log2(x))
  pow <- rev(seq.int(max(n)))
  # 'y' is the matrix of codes
  y <- t(sapply(x, \(.x) (.x %/% 2^pow) %% 2L))
  i_cols <- apply(y, 2, \(.y) any(.y != 0L))
  colnames(y) <- sprintf("code_%d", 2^pow)
  #
  possiblecodes <- apply(y, 1, \(p) {
    codes <- 2^pow[as.logical(p)]
    paste(rev(codes), collapse = ",")
  })
  data.frame(combinedvalue = x, possiblecodes, y[, i_cols])
}

x <- c(20L, 50L)
toCodes(x)
```

Comment: Am looking for the above code ('tocodes' function) in python. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution using `intToBits` to convert to binary and tidyverse libraries for subsequent data manipulation.

```r
x <- c(20L, 50L)

map_dfr(x, ~{
    bin <- intToBits(.x)
    n <- 2^(seq_len(32) - 1)
    possible <- paste(n[as.logical(bin)], collapse = ", ")
    data.frame(combinevalue = .x,
               possiblecodes = possible,
               y = rev(as.integer(bin)),
               n = rev(paste0("code_", n)))
    }) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = y)


##> # A tibble: 2 × 34
##>   combinevalue possiblecodes code_2147483648 code_1073741824 code_536870912
##>          <int> <chr>                   <int>           <int>          <int>
##> 1           20 4, 16                       0               0              0
##> 2           50 2, 16, 32                   0               0              0
##> # … with 29 more variables: code_268435456 <int>, code_134217728 <int>,
##> #   code_67108864 <int>, code_33554432 <int>, code_16777216 <int>,
##> #   code_8388608 <int>, code_4194304 <int>, code_2097152 <int>,
##> #   code_1048576 <int>, code_524288 <int>, code_262144 <int>,
##> #   code_131072 <int>, code_65536 <int>, code_32768 <int>, code_16384 <int>,
##> #   code_8192 <int>, code_4096 <int>, code_2048 <int>, code_1024 <int>,
##> #   code_512 <int>, code_256 <int>, code_128 <int>, code_64 <int>, …
```

Comment: Can we add possiblecodes column to this code

Comment: Hi @RajeshAddunuri. Now, it should look like the example you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following recursion

```
f <- function(n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  v <- 2^floor(log2(n))
  c(Recall(n - v), v)
}
```

and you will obtain

```
> f(50)
[1]  2 16 32

> f(20)
[1]  4 16
```