# Finding all sum of 2 Power value combination values of a given number in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

Data frame 1 :

| Index | Powervalue |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 32 |

Data frame 2 :

| CombinedValue |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 50 |

Someone on Stack Overflow provided the following R code.

[Finding all sum of 2 power value combination values of a given number in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74858989/finding-all-sum-of-2-power-value-combination-values-of-a-given-number-in-r)

I am looking for the same code in Python.

```r
toCodes <- function(x) {
  n <- floor(log2(x))
  pow <- rev(seq.int(max(n)))
  # 'y' is the matrix of codes
  y <- t(sapply(x, \(.x) (.x %/% 2^pow) %% 2L))
  i_cols <- apply(y, 2, \(.y) any(.y != 0L))
  colnames(y) <- sprintf("code_%d", 2^pow)
  #
  possiblecodes <- apply(y, 1, \(p) {
    codes <- 2^pow[as.logical(p)]
    paste(rev(codes), collapse = ",")
  })
  data.frame(combinedvalue = x, possiblecodes, y[, i_cols])
}

x <- c(20L, 50L)
toCodes(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import math
import pandas as pd

def calculate_values(df):
    values_list = []
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        sum_val = df.iloc[i]['sum']
        values = []
        while sum_val > 0:
            value = 2**int(math.log2(sum_val))
            values.append(value)
            sum_val -= value
        values_list.append(values)
    df['values'] = values_list
    return df

df = {'sum': [20,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df = calculate_values(df)

print(df)
```

This gives the output as:

```
   sum       values
0   20      [16, 4]
1   50  [32, 16, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Am looking for the same function in Python.

Comment: By same function do you mean a function that returns the same response? Or a function that uses exact/similar code as you have provided?

Comment: Function that returns same response. Expected output attached in the provided link