# Finding all sum of 2 Power value combination values of a given column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data frame 1 :

| Index | Powervalue |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 32 |

Data frame 2 :

| CombinedValue |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 50 |

Someone on Stack Overflow provided the following R code.

[Finding all sum of 2 power value combination values of a given number in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74858989/finding-all-sum-of-2-power-value-combination-values-of-a-given-number-in-r)

I am looking for the same code in Python.

```r
toCodes <- function(x) {
  n <- floor(log2(x))
  pow <- rev(seq.int(max(n)))
  # 'y' is the matrix of codes
  y <- t(sapply(x, \(.x) (.x %/% 2^pow) %% 2L))
  i_cols <- apply(y, 2, \(.y) any(.y != 0L))
  colnames(y) <- sprintf("code_%d", 2^pow)
  #
  possiblecodes <- apply(y, 1, \(p) {
    codes <- 2^pow[as.logical(p)]
    paste(rev(codes), collapse = ",")
  })
  data.frame(combinedvalue = x, possiblecodes, y[, i_cols])
}

x <- c(20L, 50L)
toCodes(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def to_codes(x):
    n = np.floor(np.log2(x))
    pow_ = np.flip(np.arange(n + 1))
    # 'y' is the matrix of codes
    y = np.transpose(np.array([np.floor(x / 2**pow_) % 2 for x in x]))
    i_cols = np.apply_along_axis(lambda y: np.any(y != 0), 0, y)
    colnames = ["code_" + str(int(2**pow)) for pow in pow_]
    #
    possiblecodes = np.apply_along_axis(lambda p: ",".join([str(int(codes)) for codes in np.flip(pow_[np.where(p > 0)])]), 1, y)
    return pd.DataFrame({"combinedvalue": x, "possiblecodes": possiblecodes, **{colnames[i]: y[:, i] for i in np.where(i_cols)}})
```

The function called to_codes that takes an array of integers x as input and returns a pandas DataFrame with three columns: combinedvalue, possiblecodes, and a set of columns labeled code_2^n where n is a power of 2.

Comment: Tried with provided code and getting "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scaler index" error. Can you help me with this error.

Comment: Created a dataframe df = pd.DataFrame({'index' : [0, 1, 2, 3], 'codes' : [20, 30, 40, 50]}) then to_codes(df['codes'])